# Double google translate showing up. No clue why. Just started happening randomly

Tags: google-translate

You can see it here. Does anybody have any ideas why this might be happening?

http://www.tombalding.com

You can see it at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, you have the code twice in your html, delete one and you'll be fine ;-)
I mean this one: `<img src="https://www.google.com/images/cleardot.gif" class="goog-te-gadget-icon" style="background-image: url(https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/img/te_ctrl3.gif); background-position: -65px 0px;">`

Hope I helped!